# Making true/false statements about unrealizable scenarios

Tags: real-analysis

Perhaps the title is inaccurate, but I'm attempting to show that every function $f:X$-->$Y$ is continuous at an isolated point $x$ in $X$ where $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Here's my proof:

Because $x$ is an isolated point of $X$, there exists some $k>0$ such that $B_k(x)= {x}$. Then for every $y$ belonging to $B_k(x)$ (there are none except $x$), it follows that $d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ and for every $y$ in $X$.

I consider this argument to be similar to stating that if a set has no closure points, then it contains its closure points. Is this logically equivalent?

Comment: These are perfectly acceptable arguments.

Comment: You say there are no "$y$ belonging to $B_k(x)$". But $x\in B_k(x)$.

Comment: I presume that $B_k(x)=\{a\in X:d(a,x)<k\}$. Then $B_k(x)\subseteq X$ so that $B_k(x)\cap X$ is a redundant circumlocution.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I was stating the definition of an isolated point

Comment: Wouldn't $B_k(x)=\{x\}$ be more accurate? @DavidS

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, thank you.

Comment: @DavidS for brackets in maths mode, use \{ and \}.